# Core Data: Fetch all entities

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, core-data

I want to know is there an equivalent to the MySQL `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY sth` to fetch all the results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an `NSFetchRequest` with a `nil` predicate and an appropriate `NSSortDescriptor`. On iOS, you should be using an `NSFetchedResults` controller as the query may return more items that you want in memory at once.

Comment: CoreData on iOS is pretty smart about memory utilization.  It will not load all of your rows into the returned NSArray. Actually, the object returned is a subclass of NSArray that is a proxy of an array, meaning that it implements all of the methods of NSArray, but doesn't actually have an array under the covers.  It will only load the data rows as requested by the app.

Answer (score 0):

Xhan,

The 'grammar' may be equivalent but there is some work you have to do in the application. A good starting explanation is [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html).

In general you'd want to setup a `NSFetchRequest`with the appropriate filters, sorts, etc. that you need.

-- Frank

Comment: thanks for the answer. seems a `NSFetchRequest` without an `NSPredicate` works. I'm still testing.